# How do you access divs in different wrappers with CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to talk to a div that is not within the same wrapper as a div that I am hovering over. I am using the following code to change the background color of the div picture when the div home is hovered over and they are both within the div navBar:

```
.navBar .home:hover ~ div.picture {
    background:#900; }
```

If I put home or picture within another div I am unable to access them.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: I feel like you're going about this the wrong way. if you hover on .navBar .home you want the background of a div OUTSIDE of it to change? This should probably be done with JS or you should have it nested different. Some HTML markup would help otherwise.

Comment: "Does anyone know how to get around this?" Yup, JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to reach elements that are not descendants or succeeding siblings from the element that's being hovered with just CSS3 selectors. You'll have to take the JavaScript route in order to do what you want with a different structure.

Comment: Even if I was just putting one of the divs within an extra wrapper div like this?:
<div class="navBar">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="home"> Home </div>
</div>
<div class="picture"> </div>
</div>

There is no way to have home talk to picture?

Answer (score 0):

This is where the C comes in in stylesheets. Cascading means, you're only going to be able to go under and to the sides of a the tree that you're working under.

To manipulate divs outside of the tree, you need to go the JS route above or just a really simple jquery such as

```
$(.navBar .home).hover(function () {
  $(div.picture).css("background-color","#900");
  }, 
  function () {
  $(div.picture).css("background-color","#FFF");
});
```